Handling Zod refine errors with React Hook Form
everyone! Here, I'm using React Hook Form with Ant Design's Input and TimePicker components. You can see that I'm using Zod for validation, specifically for time validation using refine, and it's working. However, it's not displaying the error message anywhere. How can I capture the error message?
The Zod validation schema image:
my reusable timepicker: 
and my example usages: 
i need an solustion to catch the error and show it on the ui.

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, don't post code as screenshots
